# Java Socket - UnknownHostException with specified address

Tags: java, sockets

I'm trying to create a socket connection to a specified address (for now, client & server are local to my computer).

First, i'm getting my ip address ( 192.168.1.82 ) and create a ServerSocket

```
String ipAddress = "192.168.1.82"; //This is get by NetworkInterface loop
int port = 4020;
InetAddress address = InetAddress.getByName(ipAddress);
this.serverSocket = new ServerSocket(port, 50, address);
```

After this, i log the socket connection:

```
String host = this.serverSocket.getInetAddress().getHostAddress();

System.out.println("Listen on " + host);
```

And i get: Listen on 192.168.1.82

After that, i start my client to connect to the socket:

```
Socket socket = new Socket("192.168.1.82", 4020);
```

this last command throw an exception:

```
java.net.UnknownHostException: 192.168.1.82
```

If i dont specify any address (i assume localhost) all works fine. But if i specify an address (i need to do this, because i must send information from client-server on LAN) i got this.

Could someone help me?

Comment: Is the space in your argument to the `Socket` constructor really here or is it a typo?

Comment: Typo. I get all this data from methods. I've hardcored the information only to write on Stackoverflow.

Comment: I'm using JPA + spring etc to save and retrieve information about IP address and with your answer i've checked the real ip address and for some reason it was saved on DB with several spaces behind...... With an trim() on ipAddress all works...... sorry.... was really difficult to debug.... white spaces are not printed... :(

Comment: Please close out this question since the answer was not even based on the question you asked and it was fixed offline

Answer (score 0):

The `Socket` constructor you are calling expects a real hostname, it will not accept an IP address as a `string`.  To pass an IP address, you have to create an `InetAddress` for it and then pass that instead:

```
InetAddress address = InetAddress.getByName("192.168.1.82");
Socket socket = new Socket(address, 4020);
```

Comment: Works for me, every time since 1997. It doesn't mention that in the Javadoc. It does specifically mention calling `InetAddress.getByName()`, which allows either a hostname or an address, and that's what happens in the source code too.

Comment: The Javadoc for the [`Socket` constructor](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/Socket.html#Socket(java.lang.String,%20int)) that the OP is calling only says that it accepts a hostname or null as input, it does not mention whether an IP address is allowed. So I would err on the side of caution and follow the documented behavior, rather than what a given system's implementation happens to accept. Clearly, the OP's system does not accept an IP address string as input, but it has to accept an `InetAddress` per the other constructor.